# Conversion of between type of timestamp in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a UNIX time stamp of "YYYY-MM-DD:24HH:MM:SS", i want to convert this to the Microsoft timestamp of "MM/DD/YY 24HH:MM".
Can someone please help me with this?

```
Source timestamp Example: "**2013-07-24:13.51.47**"
Excel timestamp example: "**07/24/13 13:51**"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that is really simple and stupid:

```
=MID(A1,6,2)&"/"&MID(A1,9,2)&"/"&MID(A1,3,2)&" "&MID(A1,12,2)&":"&MID(A1,15,2)
```

assuming A1 contains the unix time stamp.

Comment: This is perfect answer for what i was expecting and this solves my issue. :) I was looking to find out the difference between two timestamp columns in excel as i have many rows to compare. This has saved me a lot of time...  Thanks AGAIN!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would suit:

```
="**"&TEXT(MID(A1,3,10),"mm/dd/yy")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,14,5),".",":")&"**"
```

*Edit Considering clarification (completely new question?) in comments:*

```
=LEFT(A1,10)+SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,12,5),".",":")
```

Comment: This also helps of getting to the format that i want, but it does not allow me to do the difference between two columns as it give unwanted space. Thanks for your help though!!!!